# Find an object in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am making a filter that allows user clicks a checkbox to do filter. When I click a checkbox, It will add that object of item into an array of filters. When clicking again that item, I will remove that item from the array.

I am using a hard code for the object of item to make sure they are the same object every time I click. The object look like this:

`var item1 = {name: "A", id: 1};`

The below `toggleFilter` method is triggered when I click a checkbox, then dispatch an action from Vuex.

```
methods: {
            toggleFilter(categoryId) {
                var item1 = {name: "A", id: 1};

                this.$store.dispatch('filter/toggleFilter', item1);
            }
        }
```

Vuex action:

```
let actions = {
    toggleFilter({state, commit, rootState, rootGetters}, attribute) {
        let index = state.filters.indexOf(attribute);

        if (index === -1) {
            commit('addFilter', attribute);
        } else {
            commit('removeFilter', index);
        }

        console.log(state.filters);
    }
};
```

The problem is when I click again the checkbox, it doesn't remove the object from the array, it adds 1 more object into it.

[image]

One more weirdness thing is I use the exact above Vuex action for another object, something like this:

```
methods: {
            toggleFilter(option) {
                option.attributeId = this.attribute.id;
                option.type = 'attribute';

                this.$store.dispatch('filter/toggleFilter', option);
            }
        }
```

And it works. I don't know why the 1st case doesn't work, but the 2nd case works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create new object `var item1 = {name: "A", id: 1};`, so indexOf can't not find it. If you item's id is unique, you can try comparing `attribute.id`

```
let actions = {
    toggleFilter({state, commit, rootState, rootGetters}, attribute) {
    let index = state.filters.map(item => item.id).indexOf(attribute.id);
        if (index === -1) {
            commit('addFilter', attribute);
        } else {
            commit('removeFilter', index);
        }

        console.log(state.filters);
    }
};
```

Comment: There is a `find()` and a `findIndex()` method on a JS array, no need to map it. Use `state.filters.findIndex(f => f.id == attribute.id)` instead.